# variable limit to define values

Tags: r, if-statement, with-statement

I have a simple question, so lets take some basic data

```
a <- rnorm(100, mean=1, sd = 0.1)
b <- rnorm(100, mean=5, sd = 2)
c <- data.frame(a,b)
```

Now I want to redefine C$B such that if it is below a limit, the user manually defines the new variable it will take, and if it is above this limit, the values take the same as previous

```
c$b <- with(c, ifelse(b < 2, 1, # leave as exsiting value #))
```

so when b < 2, we want to assign a value of 1, otherwise use the exisitng value

Comment: using `c` as a variable in R may not be the best idea, considering `c` is a valid command.

Comment: Try `with(c, ifelse(b < 2, 1, b))`

Comment: thanks @ Ricky, just an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are using `ifelse`, try

```
 c$b <- with(c, ifelse(b < 2, 1, b))
```

This doesn't even require `ifelse`.  We can get the logical index of values less than 2 in the 'b' column (`c$b <2`) and assign those values to 1.

```
c$b[c$b<2] <- 1
```